# When I extract a zip file on my hosted server the permissions are different than my own server. How do I simulate the extraction on my hosted server?

Tags: files, permissions, zip

I have an application, let's say Bootstraptor. When I extract it on my hosted server, it extracts fine and all the directories have permissions 755 and the files have 644. And the application works immediately if I open it in a browser.

When I extract the files on my own server, it extracts as 700 and so the application doesn't work when I try it in a browser.

I can change all the directories and files manually, but, is there a better way to do this?

I am using Linux Mint Debian v2. I installed apache2 v2.4.10 as my web server. I am using Caja 1.10.0 to "Extract Here". I have 7z v9.20 installed, which I assume is doing the extraction. I tried it at the command line and the same thing with the permissions happens, it's 700.

Comment: Use `tar` so that modes are preserved, instead of zip. Also check the `umask` of the server.

Comment: tar didn't work, b/c it's a zip file, but unzip did and preserved the permissions. Now it works fine when I open it in a browser, thanks. I read somewhere that 7z doesn't preserve permissions, so that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a different umask on your personal server.

```
(umask 022; 7z x foo.zip)
```

Should do the trick.  `(subshell)` to avoid having to set umask back again for the rest of your shell session.